# SQL How to count case

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to case out a select statement. However, there are multiple results for 7am 8am 9am etc. I'd like the results to show:

Count   Time
10      7am
6       8am

etc. Instead, it is showing all the 7ams all the 8ams etc.

```
select
case
when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 07:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '7am'
when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 08:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '8am'
when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 09:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '9am'
when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 10:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '10am'
when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '11am'
END as Time
from archivedqueue aq
where aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
```

Comment: Well, you need to actually use `COUNT`: `SELECT COUNT(*), case...... FROM ... WHERE .... GROUP BY case....`

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
select COUNT(*), Time
FROM
(SELECT
    case
    when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 07:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '7am'
    when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 08:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '8am'
    when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 09:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '9am'
    when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 10:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '10am'
    when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '11am'
    END as Time
    from archivedqueue aq
    where aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )) tempTable
GROUP BY Time
```

`Group by Time` will combine all the 7ams,8ams, together. `Count(*)` counts the number of rows in each group.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, Time
  FROM (SELECT case
               when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '7am'
               when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '8am'
               when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '9am'
               when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '10am'
               when aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) then '11am'
               END as Time
          FROM archivedqueue aq
         WHERE aq.datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
       ) name_required
 GROUP BY Time
 ORDER BY Time;
```

The sub-query is what you wrote (apart from a fixup in the second TO_DATE in the various BETWEEN conditions — it is easier to spot problems when you can see the code without horizontal scrolling!), marginally reformatted.  Note that the ORDER BY is imperfect because the sort is text-based (so the `10am` and `11am` entries will appear before the `7am` to `9am` entries).  If you don't like that, use a text-sortable format such as `07` or `0700` or `0700-07:59` instead of the 'am'-tagged times.

This is not extensible.  You need to work harder on what's in the CASE statement.

Maybe:

```
TO_CHAR(aq.datestarted, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00') AS time
```

The restriction condition in the WHERE clause then provides the correct limits on the search.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, TO_CHAR(aq.datestarted, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:00') AS time
  FROM archivedqueue aq
 WHERE aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date('22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                          AND to_date('22-MAY-2014 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 GROUP BY Time
 ORDER BY Time;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it working how you'd expect, use what's below... However, there's probably a better way than hardcoding dates and times.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', 
        CASE 
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 07:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '7am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 08:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '8am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 09:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '9am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 10:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '10am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '11am'
        END AS 'Time'
FROM archivedqueue aq
WHERE aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' 
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 07:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '7am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 08:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 08:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '8am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 09:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 09:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '9am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 10:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 10:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '10am'
            WHEN aq.datestarted BETWEEN to_date( '22-MAY-2014 11:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) AND to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) THEN '11am'
        END
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to show the order times chronologically?

Comment: In SQL Server, `ORDER BY 2` would order by the second column.  That may possible work in this RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

You just want this:

```
select count(*) count, hour(datestarted) time
from rchivedqueue
where datestarted between to_date( '22-MAY-2014 07:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) and to_date( '22-MAY-2014 " 11:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
group by hour(datestarted)
```

Comment: `datepart` isn't a valid Oracle function (and the use of `to_date` hints to op using it)

Comment: @Lamak  We'll see if he tells us. Whatever database he is using, this approach is better than reinventing the wheel with 24 cases - one for each hour

Comment: S/he is already using the query, so we can safely assume s/he is using Oracle. On the other hand, though your answer is "cleaner", if there is an index on that column your version won't allow its use, and the `CASE` version will (even if that version can be writter in a better form).

Comment: ...and for 365 or 366 dates per year, for 20 years...  You could use a formatting TO_CHAR() that gives the date and hour as output.

Comment: It's Oracle. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @lamak an index wouldn't be used no matter what is done in the case/function; the index is used based on the where clause of this query, and that is unchanged, so either all the queries on this page or none will use an index.

Comment: @you try it now - I've changed the syntax to suit oracle

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, the range given is just one morning. As stated, the question can be answered, and the requested output given, using a simple extraction if the hour.